# LESS syntax for .mixin > *

Tags: css, less, mixins

I am using LESS and im trying for a type of mixin.

I have this mixin:

```
.mixin, .mixin > * {
    font:arial;
}
```

and i want to use it as a mix in so.

```
.my-class {
    color:#000;
    .mixin;
}
```

becomes

```
.my-class {
    color:#000;
}

.my-class, .my-class > * {
    font:arial;
}
```

But it doesnt work, probobly because i cannot use mixins like that. Or can I? How do i write them then? Cannot find this information in the documentation of LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was this.

```
.mixin {
    font:arial;

    > * {
        font:arial;
    }
}

.my-class {
    color:#000;
    .mixin;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
.amixin {
    font: Arial;
}

.mixin, .mixin > * {
    .amixin;
}

.my-class {
    color: #000;
    .amixin;
}
```